# App crash. Log shows reason: 'Invalid query. You must not specify a starting point before specifying the order by.'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data by set limit and sort data according to timestamp, but it crash when running app with this error message:

`Invalid query. You must not specify a starting point before specifying the order by.`

I dont know why this is happening. How to solve it?

I need data sequence and sorted.

```
 if (self.snapLastkey == "") {
        self.arrayTask = []
        self.arrayKeys = []
        self.arraySelectedTask = []
        query = taskRef.whereField(kUUID, isEqualTo: userID).whereField(kIsCompleted, isEqualTo: false).limit(to: kLimit).order(by: kTaskDate, descending: false)
    }else{
        query = taskRef.whereField(kUUID, isEqualTo: userID).whereField(kIsCompleted, isEqualTo: false).limit(to: kLimit).start(afterDocument: self.snapLastDocument!).order(by: kTaskDate, descending: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to combine `orderBy` and `startAtDocument`, you need to specify the order first. It's likely that your variable inside the `else` statement is causing this error, so try changing the query to:

```
query = taskRef.whereField(kUUID, isEqualTo: userID).whereField(kIsCompleted, isEqualTo: false).limit(to: kLimit).order(by: kTaskDate, descending: false).start(afterDocument: self.snapLastDocument!)
```

Although not entirely clear in the documentation, the examples in the [use a document snapshot to define the query cursor section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) do show using `order` before `start`:

> ```
> let sfSizeOrBigger = db.collection("cities")
>     .order(by: "population")
>     .start(atDocument: document)
> ```

Comment: still not getting exact result :(

Comment: If this has answered your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Further issues should be posted as a new question to attract more attention and answers.